# Can the word 'applicable' be used bidirectionally?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to name fields right now, and I stumbled upon the usage of the word `applicable`.

I have discounts (i.e. discount codes) which are usable for a certain products. So the discount is `applicable` to a product. But should I also say the product is `applicable` for the discount?

My thinking is, that I apply a discount to a product, which suggests an order or hierarchiy. So it wouldn't be precise to say 'these 4 products are applicable to this discount(code)'.

But then, what would be a better word? Valid Products?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I’d say _available_.

Comment: Eligible for the discount is the way I'd say it.

Comment: @KarlG You mean as in 'these products are available for this discount code'?

Comment: Yes. A discount is available for these products or these products are available for discount. Works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Discounts usually apply to products and/or customer types but to say that products apply to discounts, or that products are applicable to discounts, would be bizarre.

You could say that products may attract discounts.